# How do I update values in a table from another table with the exact same fields?

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I have a table called `AA`.
I distributed 2 copies for an update.
In 1 copy, called `Table1`, all values in `Field2` are updated updated where the value in Field1 is `AA`.
In the other copy `Table2` all values are updated where the value in `Field1` is `BB`

My question is:
How do I update table `AA` with this new information?

[image]

Comment: ¿So you want to update Field2 values from Table AA with values from Table1 WHERE Field1=AA? and same for Table2 but WHERE Field1 =BB?

Comment: That's right :)

Comment: And what are the common fields between all 3 tables? is the same ID for each row in each table?

Comment: The common field is indeed the ID-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will update `AA.Field2` with values from `Table1.Field2` if `ID` match and where `Field1=`AA``

```
UPDATE AA INNER JOIN Table1 ON (AA.Field1 = Table1.Field1) AND (AA.Id = Table1.Id) SET AA.Field2 = [Table1].[Field2]
WHERE (((Table1.Field1)='AA'));
```

You can make a second query but with parameters of TableB.

```
UPDATE AA INNER JOIN Table2 ON (AA.Field1 = Table2.Field1) AND (AA.Id = Table2.Id) SET AA.Field2 = [Table2].[Field2]
WHERE (((Table2.Field1)="AA"));
```

**UPDATE:** You can make all updates on a single Query:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN AA ON (Table2.Field1 = AA.Field1) AND (Table2.Id = AA.Id)) ON (Table1.Field1 = AA.Field1) AND (Table1.Id = AA.Id) SET AA.Field2 = IIf([AA]![Field1]="AA",[Table1]![Field2],[Table2]![Field2]);
```